# checkbox with ordered selection array for php

Tags: php, jquery

```
<form method='post' action=''>
 <label for="x1">X1</label>
 <input id="x1" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="x1" />

 <label for="x2">X2</label>
 <input id="x2" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="x2" />

 <label for="x3">X3</label>
 <input id="x3" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="x3" />

 <label for="x4">X4</label>
 <input id="x4" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="x4" />

 <button type='submit' name='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

In this form How can i get the selection order of the `checkboxe`s inside the php array

Just if i submitted the form after clicking **x4 > x2 > x3 > x1**

i want to get ordered in the array as it is selected **checkbox[x4, x2, x3, x1]**

The normal array i get is as it is ordered **checkbox[x1, x2, x3, x4]**.

Comment: You'd need some JavaScript that perhaps changes the index of the checkbox-array, it can't be done in PHP. This gets sent from top to bottom to the server, so PHP doesn't really know in what order anything happened in, it all comes at once.

Comment: @Qirel Is there any example of how to do that?

Comment: Like I said, you'd need some JS that changes something when you click it. Perhaps a change in the keys (so you set `name="checkbox[1]"` when the first one is checked, `name="checkbox[2]"` when the second is checked, etc).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Comment: @JurijJazdanov array_reverse wont' work. As OP wants the order of array the same as the order in which the check boxes were selected by the user.

Comment: @Qirel I'm trying not to change the keys to be used as orders, Since i'm going to use it for a future use, Is there another solution except that, Unless it is possible to use two keys at once.

Comment: @Axon - Why do you actually need to track the order in which the boxes were checked? We might be able to propose you an alternative. 
As mentioned by Qirel, it isn't possible with PHP only.

Comment: @AwaisUmar I'm trying to use it for something collects different checkboxes order, then make words out of all of them as the user selected. Something like  children game to order words to make a sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the clicked  order using jquery

push the `value`  to array on change event.if is checked push to the array.is unchecked `value` remove from array

Join the array with `,` add the value to hidden  input .you could post this value to  server

```js
var arr=[]
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    arr.push($(this).val())
  } else {
    var r =arr.indexOf($(this).val())
    arr.splice(r, 1)
}
$('input[type=hidden]').val(arr.join(',')) //for  server use
console.log(arr)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method='post' action=''>
  <label for="x1">X1</label>
  <input id="x1" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="x1" />

  <label for="x2">X2</label>
  <input id="x2" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="x2" />

  <label for="x3">X3</label>
  <input id="x3" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="x3" />

  <label for="x4">X4</label>
  <input id="x4" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="x4" />
<input type="hidden" name="clickedorder" >
  <button type='submit' name='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Updated**

change the label value depend on clicking order

```js
var arr=[]
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    arr.push($(this).val())
  } else {
    var r =arr.indexOf($(this).val())
    arr.splice(r, 1)
}
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(a){
//console.log(arr.indexOf($(this).val()))
  if(arr.indexOf($(this).val())>-1){
     $(this).prev('label').text($(this).val().toUpperCase()+'-'+(arr.indexOf($(this).val())+1))
  }else{
    $(this).prev('label').text($(this).val().toUpperCase())
  }
})
$('input[type=hidden]').val(arr.join(',')) //for  server use

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method='post' action=''>
  <label for="x1">X1</label>
  <input id="x1" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="x1" />

  <label for="x2">X2</label>
  <input id="x2" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="x2" />

  <label for="x3">X3</label>
  <input id="x3" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="x3" />

  <label for="x4">X4</label>
  <input id="x4" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="x4" />
<input type="hidden" name="clickedorder" >
  <button type='submit' name='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Create a hidden field and set its value as `arr` it will be posted to server otherwise exercise is futile

Comment: Just once thing use some other name as `orderedCheckbox` instead of `name="checkbox[]" `

Comment: Is it possible to add for each label the order number of the selected checkboxes? like if we selected `X4` first it becomes int he label `X4-1`? I thought about getting the `key number+1' then append it.

Comment: @Axon see my updated answer.My code also auto calculate order if you unchecked also

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a jquery function like this:

Add a common class to all checkboxes like class="ckbox"
then,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selected_boxes = [];
    $('.ckbox').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            selected_boxes.push($(this).val());
            $(this).prev().attr('for',$(this).val());
        }
        else{    //  When uncheck the checkbox.
            selected_boxes.splice( $.inArray($(this).val(), selected_boxes), 1 );
        }
    });
});
```

Then post this JS variable to your php code. It will give all the values in sequence in which you had selected.

Comment: Well, This is a simple way and i guess i will need to add the remove part, But i guess it need some fixation

Comment: With Remove part, you mean when unchecking the checkbox ?

Comment: Yes, Also the`(this.val())` doesn't seem to be valid in the console

Comment: @Axon, I am updating my answer.

Comment: @Axon, hope this is helpful now. I have changed if condition and I have also put `else` part to remove checkbox value from array.

Comment: Works perfectly now, Is it possible to give each label the array order number of its `for''` input? Just as the answer above.

Comment: Yes, we can do that. I have updated my answer again for this.